Or clause in Get-CimInstance filter
This should be simple but I just haven't been able to figure it out. How to I implement an or clause with a Get-CimInstance filter? I'm filling an XAML listview with processes and I only want to return powershell, powershell_ise or pwsh but I can't figure out how to do an -or clause properly. I've tried:
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name like 'Powershell%'" -or "Name like 'pwsh%'" 

Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter ("Name like 'Powershell%'") -or "(Name like 'pwsh%'")

but these don't work. I get "Get-CimInstance : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'or'."
I would think this would be easier than this.

Take out the dash in "or".  The syntax is like "where" in sql.  Also it should be one long quote.
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name like 'powershell%' or 
  name like 'pwsh%'" 

ProcessId Name           HandleCount WorkingSetSize VirtualSize
--------- ----           ----------- -------------- -----------
6056      powershell.exe 774         47206400       2204070068224

Note that the commandline property is useful compared to powershell 5.1's get-process:
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -filter 'name = "chrome.exe"' | select commandline

"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --origin-trial-disabled-features=ElementCapture --restart --restart

Adding commandline to powershell 5.1's get-process:
# add commandline property to get-process like powershell 7
$updateTypeData = @{
    TypeName   = 'System.Diagnostics.Process'
    MemberName = 'CommandLine'
    MemberType = [Management.Automation.PSMemberTypes]::ScriptProperty
    Force      = $true
    Value      = { (Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = 
                   $($this.Id)").CommandLine }
}
Update-TypeData @updateTypeData

Query with wmic for extra awkwardness:
wmic process where 'name like "powershell%" or name like "pwsh%"'


ahh. Just a matter of getting the syntax right. thanks. that did it.

js2010's helpful answer addresses your question as asked.

To offer a simpler alternative based on Get-Process:
Get-Process powershell*, pwsh

Note:

The output objects representing the matching processes will be of a different type, namely System.Diagnostics.Process, with differently named and/or different properties than the Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#root/cimv2/Win32_Process instances that the Get-CimInstance command returns.

Unlike in the CIM query, Get-Process's -Name aka -ProcessName parameter / result-object property do not include the executable's filename extension (*.exe), so, for instance, pwsh alone is enough to match processes created from the pwsh.exe executable; the powershell* wildcard expression matches both powershell.exe and powershell_ISE.exe processes.



would this allow me to kill the process based on the processid? that's my ultimate goal and is in a question I just posted. I just tested it and I do get the procid but I like the way Get-CimInstance returns the info better. Thanks for your input though. I gave you a bump for it.

Thanks, @MattWilliamson. You can directly pipe the Get-Process output to Stop-Process in order to forcefully terminate the matching processes.
